# How to make things done on Preferences being changed?

Tags: android, settings, preferences, preferencescreen

I've set up a Preference Screen as a settings option in my App, but I am totally confused about how to make the changes done when user selects or changes an Option.

**Here's the xml code of my PreferenceScreen:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
        <RingtonePreference
            android:summary="Choose a Ringtone"
            android:title="Notification Ringtone"
            android:key="ringtonePref" />
        <ListPreference
            android:title="Notification Timer"
            android:summary="Select when to Notify"
            android:dialogTitle="Show Notification after every:"
            android:positiveButtonText="OK"
            android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
            android:entries="@array/entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/entries"
            android:key="listPrefs" />
        <ListPreference
            android:title="LED Color"
            android:summary="Choose LED Color"
            android:positiveButtonText="OK"
            android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
            android:entries="@array/colors"
            android:entryValues="@array/colors"
            android:key="listPrefs2" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="LED"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:summary="Flash LED or Not"
            android:key="checkBoxPrefs2"/>
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="Vibrate"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:summary="Vibrate on receiving Notification"
            android:key="checkBoxPrefs3" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Invite">
        <Preference android:summary="Send invitation to more peoples so that\nthey can also Learn more and more Duas."/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Version">
        <Preference
            android:key="versionPrefs"
            android:summary="Version 1.0\nThank you for Downloading the App." />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**and here is my Settings.class:**

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        //setting the properties of Action Bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'><strong>Settings</strong></font>"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")));
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

*I don't know what code should I add to onPreferenceChange to make my Preferences actually do the change.*

Please tell me.

Any **help** would be highly ***Appreciated***.

Thanks for your **precious time**.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html

Comment: @Hammad Nasir If u want to save ur settings use SharedPreferences Please check the following link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @shylendra I want something like suppose there is an option given of Vibration, if user checks it than vibration will happen and if user will uncheck it the vibration will not happen. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vibration

```
CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPrefs3 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkBoxPrefs3");
    checkBoxPrefs3.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
            if ((Boolean) o) {
                checkBoxPrefs3.setChecked(true); 
                // vibration for 800 milliseconds
                ((Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(800);
                // TODO vibrate
            } else {
                checkBoxPrefs3.setChecked(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Required permission to add inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**How to Apply For your App?**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean vibrate = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkBoxPrefs3", true);

Notification notification = new Notification(icon,
                    "message", when);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            if (vibrate) {
                   notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            }

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext,
                    "ticker",
                    "message", contentIntent);
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(count, notification);
```

Comment: You did'nt get me bro, I want to set this as a _setting of my App that when the user **checks** the vibration checkbox the device will vibrate when notification will be received and if user **unchecks** it the device will not vibrate when Notification is received._ Please **help** with this too.

Comment: **Thanks for this answer** bro, it **Worked!** Now please tell me about _ListPreferences_ also. I have posted in my question, there I have given an option that after how much hours the users would like to get Informed. for ex - after every 2 hours or 4 hours and so on. _So for ex- if a user selects 2 hours **how should the App be able to notify user after every 2 hours? Thanks again. Please HELP with this also**._

Comment: set alarm in preference change

Comment: But bro Alarm would be set for only a particular interval and I want it to set for 5 different time intervals as user's choice. How to?

Comment: you need to set five alarm  for with seleceted time interval

Comment: OK, and how to give references like if user selects 2 hours then alarm will fire after every 2 hours or if user selects 8 hours then alarm will fire after every 8 hours.

Comment: use serRepeat() method to play alarm repeatedly

Comment: You didn't got it, this I know how to repeat Alarms but I am asking that how to set it accordingly for ex-if user selects to notify him/her after every 8 hours, so how would App fire Alarm after every 8 hours and then if same user changes it to 10 hours than how would the Alarm be fired after every 10 hours. This is what I am asking. Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58152/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-hammad-nasir).

Answer (score 1):

On your PreferenceActivity

- Initialize your `CheckBoxPreference`
- Add `OnPreferenceChangeListener`
- Do whatever you want on change..

Here's an example:

```
    CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPrefs3 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkBoxPrefs3");
    checkBoxPrefs3.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
            if ((Boolean) o) {
                checkBoxPrefs3.setChecked(true); 
                // TODO vibrate
            } else {
                checkBoxPrefs3.setChecked(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please tell more briefly. What to do here: `// TODO vibrate` . _What code should be written here in order to vibrate when **checked** and don't vibrate when **unchecked**._

Comment: Please help with this.

Comment: You did'nt get me bro, I want to set this as a setting of my App that when the user checks the vibration checkbox the device will vibrate when notification will be received and if user unchecks it the device will not vibrate when Notification is received. Please help with this too.

Answer (score 0):

Android saves it automatically to your `SharedPreferences`.
You can always get the desired value by calling:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
boolean led = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkBoxPrefs2", true);
```

Where `checkBoxPrefs2` is key defined in your layout and `true` is default value.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I want something like suppose there is an option given of Vibration, _if user checks it than vibration will happen and if user will uncheck it the vibration will not happen_. Please **help** me with this.